Как правильно задать вложенные циклы для такой формулы B, C список одинаковых размеров

Нужно правильно сделать вложенные циклы для двух списков B, C перемножить друг на друга

Ну тут два вложенных цикла, суммирование, умножение. Простейшая арифметика. В чём проблема? Что вы уже сами пробовали сделать? И главное - на каком языке программирования то?

Python, недавно только начал изучать....

Ок. Представьте, что у вас в формуле одна сумма и один список B. Сможете код написать? Напишите. Добавьте его в вопрос. Начните с малого. Напишете - можно будет думать дальше, как это развить. Дальше нужно попробовать добавить в код второй список. А потом и вторую сумму. "Есть слона по частям" это называется. Никто не рождается Эйнштейном, все начинают с малого.
